# How to use jQuery to execute a Bootstrap data-toggle action?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a Bootstrap accordion.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-xs-4" id="more-info-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
    I want to input more stuff.
  </button>
</div>

<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    This is another form field.
  </div>               
</div>
```

When I click on the `#more-info-button` I start to execute Bootstrap.js' accordion animation. The class for `#collapseOne` goes from `.collapse` to `.collapsing` to `.collapse-in`, and vice versa.

I want the same thing to happen, but when I put a checkmark on a checkbox instead:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revealTextInputField" value="">Check me to review another text input field.
  </label>
</div>
```

The idea is that if a user checks this, an additional form field will drop down via the accordion.

Of course I can do this with jQuery's `.toggle` or `add/remove class` methods, but there are 3 different classes and they animate... so I'm not too sure how to go about this.

**EDIT**

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/pb1pfUxino

Comment: A [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) would help greatly here

Comment: what is the question? $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });  or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('input[name="revealTextInputField"]').change(function(){
    $('#collapseOne').collapse(this.checked? 'show' : 'hide')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xLuKV/)

Comment: That worked. I'm confused why it worked though. There's no `.collapse` method in jQuery, right? http://jquery.com/?s=collapse

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny it is provided by [bootstrap collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Comment: ahhhhh... I see. Ok, should have read the docs more carefully ><